# How to get corresponding quarter of previous year in Scala

Tags: java, scala, date, apache-spark, localdate

I have a date string with me in the format - "20202" ["yyyyQ"]. Is there a way to get the corresponding quarter of previous year ?

ex- for 20202 , it should be 20192

Comment: `d.take(4).toInt - 1 + "" + d(4)`. If that pesky `"` bothers you: `s"${d.take(4).toInt - 1}${d(4)}"`

Comment: I thought of using some Date time formatter to solve this, But this one will serve the purpose :) Thanks!!! :)

Comment: The [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project has a `YearQuarter` class that is just right for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to the other answers is using my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) and its class [CalendarQuarter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarQuarter.html). Example:

```
    String input = "20202";

    ChronoFormatter<CalendarQuarter> f =
        ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
            "yyyyQ", 
            PatternType.CLDR, 
            Locale.ENGLISH, 
            CalendarQuarter.chronology());
    CalendarQuarter cq = f.parse(input);
    CalendarQuarter quarterInPreviousYear = cq.minus(Years.ONE);
    System.out.println(quarterInPreviousYear); // 2019-Q2
```

Two main advantages of this solution are:

- Calendar quarters are also intervals so it is easy to iterate over them daily.
- Internationalization is supported for more than 90 languages, even style-based.

Interval example:

```
    for (PlainDate date : quarterInPreviousYear) {
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

Output:

```
> 2019-04-01 
> 2019-04-02 
> 2019-04-03
> ...
```

Printing example in Danish:

```
    ChronoFormatter<CalendarQuarter> printer =
        ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
            "QQQQ y", 
            PatternType.CLDR, 
            new Locale("da"), 
            CalendarQuarter.chronology());
    System.out.println(printer.print(quarterInPreviousYear)); // 2. kvartal 2019
```

Comment: Meno Hochschild - Most of us on SO have learnt something from you on date-time topic. I just tested your feature-rich library and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Adding `System.out.println(f.format(quarterInPreviousYear));` as well after `System.out.println(quarterInPreviousYear);` can be helpful for beginners.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks for your feedback. The expression `System.out.println(quarterInPreviousYear);` indirectly uses the method `toString()` which produces an ISO-like style ("2019-Q2"). But of course, using the formatter for printing is more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for this one  :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eTQM4VsRTjSvMvyleqOV2w) showing one approach.

```
val d = "20202"
(d.substring(0,4).toInt - 1).toString + d.substring(4)  // 20192: String
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update (thanks to [Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64464257/how-to-get-corresponding-quarter-of-previous-year-in-scala/64469462#comment113998667_64469462))

Given below is pure `DateTimeFormatter` solution:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.temporal.IsoFields;

import org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given string
        String str = "20202";

        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
                                .appendValue(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR, 1)
                                .toFormatter();

        // Parse the converted string
        YearQuarter yearQuarter = YearQuarter.parse(str, dtf);
        System.out.println(yearQuarter.format(dtf));

        // A year ago
        System.out.println(yearQuarter.minusYears(1).format(dtf));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20202
20192
```

### Original answer:

I recommend you do it using [ThreeTenExtra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. The only problem that you will have to deal with is converting the given string into `yyyy-Q` format which you can easily do using a regex as shown below:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given string
        String str = "20202";

        // Convert the given string into yyyy-Q format
        str = str.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d{1,2})", "$1-$2");

        // Parse the converted string
        YearQuarter yearQuarter = YearQuarter.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-Q"));

        // Define output format
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuQ");
        System.out.println(yearQuarter.format(outputFormat));

        // A year ago
        System.out.println(yearQuarter.minusYears(1).format(outputFormat));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20202
20192
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `(\\d{4})(\\d{1,2})` specifies two groups: the first group having 4 digits and the second group having one or two digit(s)
2. The replacement string `$1-$2` specifies `group(1)-group(2)`

Comment: @OleV.V. - Thanks for the feedback. I had tried `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyQ")` but it didn't work and therefore I had to use replacement using regex. I've updated the answer to incorporate your second suggestion.

Comment: The pattern yyyyQ will work in my lib Time4J, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought of using some Date time formatter to solve this, …

Do! I would immediately prefer the solution by Arvind Kumar Avinash using `YearQuarter` of the ThreeTen Extra library. In case you find it overkill to add an external library to your project (or your team or boss thinks so), we can also do without it, only less elegantly. Here’s a Java solution that I think you can hand translate to Scala:

```
    DateTimeFormatter quarterFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
            .appendValue(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR, 1)
            .parseDefaulting(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1)
            .toFormatter();
    
    String quarterString = "20202";
    
    YearMonth firstMonthOfQuarter
            = YearMonth.parse(quarterString, quarterFormatter);
    YearMonth firstMonthOfQuarterLastYear = firstMonthOfQuarter.minusYears(1);
    String quarterPreviousYearString
            = firstMonthOfQuarterLastYear.format(quarterFormatter);
    
    System.out.println(quarterPreviousYearString);
```

Output is the desired:

> 20192

### Advantages of the right data type

> Could you please explain what advantages usage of DateTime may have in
> this case over simple string manipulation and conversion to int?

Edit: When you need to read some number, for example an ID number, from input and print it again on output, do you read it into an `int` or a `String`? Most of use `int` (or `long` or `BigInteger`). Why? Your question is similar.

The advantages of using `YearQuarter` or `YearMonth` include (and probably are not limited to):

- **Self-explanatory code:** `val d = "20202"` tells nothing about the meaning of this piece of data. A variable of type `YearQuarter` very clearly tells the reader that this variable hold a quarter of year. `YearMonth` is the best approximation in the standard Java library and already less clear about why we are using it here, but still a sizeable advantage over `String`.
- **Validation for free:** By parsing the string using the formatter, if the string doesn’t denote a valid quarter of year, we will be sure to be notified through an exception.
- **Further validation cheap:** If you want further validation, for example the quarter must be after 2nd quarter of 2019 but not in the future, this is easy and straightforward with java.time (it can be done with the string too, but the code will be hard to read unless you explain over several lines of comment what you’ve got going).
- **Ready for future requirements:** If one day you need to do something more with the quarter, like for example finding the first and the last day of the quarter or the quarter before it, this will be a walk in the park because the class offers a very rich set of operations.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: Wow! This is a great solution purely using Java-8.

Comment: IMHO not exactly great, @ArvindKumarAvinash, but workable. Thank you anyway! I did something similar at work recently to evade the trouble of convincing 10 team mates to add ThreeTen Extra, but after writing the code I’m no longer sure I made the right decision there.

Comment: Could you please explain what advantages usage of *DateTime* may have in this case over simple string manipulation and conversion to int?

Comment: Thanks Ole and Arvind. But as @jrook asked is there any special advantage

Comment: @jrook - The advantage of using date-time API is that you will all features of date-time manipulation e.g. if you want to add/subtract a month, year, day etc. or you want to deal with time-zone information etc. You will never have these things available when you do simple string manipulation and conversion to int.